# Find the tangent line of $-x+e2x^3-1$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus

First I tried to find the derivative:

$$f'(x)=6ex^2-1$$

(You can confirm [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20-x%2Be2x%5E3-1))

Then I tried to find the derivative at $x=0$:

$$f'(0) = -1$$

Then I tried to find the equation of the tangent line using the point $(0;-1)$ of $f(x)$:

$$-1 = -0+b \Leftrightarrow -1 = b$$

And so the tangent line is $y=-x-1$

But my book states the solution is $y=-x+\frac{1}{e}$. Even WolframAlpha seems to disagree with my book (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+at+x%3D0+of+-x%2Be2x%5E3-1)

What went wrong?

It would be pretty ironic if my book was wrong, because this exercise is from my schoolbook and was in one of the national exams, and this section of the book is supposedly for practicing for the exams.

Comment: is $e$ the Euler number?

Comment: Your computation is right, the book must have  a typo

Comment: and WolframAlpha too

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, it is.

Comment: Did you type it right? Are you sure it isn't $f(x)=-x+e^{2x^3-1}$

Comment: If so the book would be right...http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+at+x%3D0+of+-x%2Be%5E(2x%5E3-1)

Comment: @randomgirl I'm 100% sure. http://imgur.com/a/OBGcp Yeah it's probably just a typo, but still ironic.

Comment: It should probably be $e^{2x^3-1}$, usually one would not write $e2x^3$ but $2ex^3$.